# Integral of Function - Keras Custom Loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a custom loss function which integrates an input curve. 
The curve can be a mix of polynomial, exponential, and sinusoidal.

The inputs are of the form: [x0, x1, ...., x9] where x0-x3 are the polynomial coefficients, x4-x6 are the exponential coefficients and x7-x9 are the sinusoidal coefficients.

**EDIT:** I got the following to compile but I would like to have a much more precise integration result.

```
def integrate_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    x_range = K.arange(-5.0, 5.0, step=1, dtype='float32')

    y_true_pol = y_true[0]*x_range**3+y_true[1]*x_range**2+y_true[2]*x_range+y_true[3]
    y_pred_pol = y_pred[0]*x_range**3+y_pred[1]*x_range**2+y_pred[2]*x_range+y_pred[3]
    diff_pol = K.abs(K.sum(y_true_pol - y_pred_pol))

    y_true_exp = y_true[4]*K.exp(y_true[5]*(x_range-y_true[6]))
    y_pred_exp = y_pred[4]*K.exp(y_pred[5]*(x_range-y_pred[6]))
    diff_exp = K.abs(K.sum(y_true_exp - y_pred_exp))

    y_true_sin = y_true[7]*K.sin(y_true[8]*(x_range-y_true[9]))
    y_pred_sin = y_pred[7]*K.sin(y_pred[8]*(x_range-y_pred[9]))
    diff_sin = K.abs(K.sum(y_true_sin - y_pred_sin))

    area_between = diff_pol + diff_exp + diff_sin
    return area_between
```

**EDIT:** This produces the following errors:

```
Epoch 1/150
 9/18 [==============>...............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 41.94232018-09-13 13:03:56.343324: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Invalid argument: slice index 4 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
2018-09-13 13:03:56.343324: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Invalid argument: slice index 2 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
2018-09-13 13:03:56.343324: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Invalid argument: slice index 3 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
2018-09-13 13:03:56.343329: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Invalid argument: slice index 6 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
2018-09-13 13:03:56.343331: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Invalid argument: slice index 5 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
2018-09-13 13:03:56.343485: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Invalid argument: slice index 8 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
2018-09-13 13:03:56.343556: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Invalid argument: slice index 9 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
2018-09-13 13:03:56.343593: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Invalid argument: slice index 7 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
2018-09-13 13:03:56.450277: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Invalid argument: slice index 4 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
         [[Node: loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_arg_dense_2_target_1_0_1/_243, loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8/stack, loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8/stack_1, loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8/stack_2)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "training.py", line 152, in <module>
    verbose=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2230, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1883, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2482, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 997, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1132, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: slice index 4 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
         [[Node: loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_arg_dense_2_target_1_0_1/_243, loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8/stack, loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8/stack_1, loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8/stack_2)]]
         [[Node: loss_1/mul/_269 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1800_loss_1/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8', defined at:
  File "training.py", line 130, in <module>
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), loss=integrate_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 830, in compile
    sample_weight, mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 429, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "training.py", line 47, in integrate_loss
    y_true_exp = y_true[4]*K.exp(y_true[5]*(x_range-y_true[6]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 499, in _SliceHelper
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 663, in strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3515, in strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): slice index 4 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
         [[Node: loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_arg_dense_2_target_1_0_1/_243, loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8/stack, loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8/stack_1, loss_1/dense_2_loss/strided_slice_8/stack_2)]]
         [[Node: loss_1/mul/_269 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1800_loss_1/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    debug('worker got sentinel -- exiting')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

As can be seen above, this stops working at random spots (I tested many times with some working properly and decreasing on validation as needed). I would also like to have a better working integration function as currently it just takes the height of each function (width is 1) which produces large errors.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to use numpy operation in the loss function.  How about rewriting it by tensor operations?

Comment: @KotaMori you are right, I checked with another link which mentioned that you need to use keras backend functions to allow for gradient calculations in the backend. Please see edits in original post for new issues.

Comment: Seems to be an issue of batch size vs y_true[x] for example when I use batch_size=1 and y_true[9] it gives slice warning, but with y_true[0][9] it works fine. How can I modify this to make it work with batch_size=16 and for x_range in -5.0 to 5.0 with 0.01 steps?

Comment: What are the shapes of your various inputs (`y_true` and `y_pred`)? You might be slicing them wrong.

Comment: Also, can you provide a MCVE (minimal, **complete**, verifiable example) that I can run?